# Magento2 : How To Get First Table Column From Join Query Result(From Duplicate Columns)

Tags: magento2, join-table

**Table1** - col_name col_city col_tid

**Table 2** - col_id col_city

In Magento2 i want  col_name,col_city from Table1 And col_id from Table2 Using Join Query
And col_city is in both table so i just want col_city from Table1.

i already tried with below join query

```
    $this->setMainTable('Table1');

    $this->getSelect()
         ->joinLeft(
                array('tbl2' => $this->getTable('Table2')),
                'main_table.col_tid = tbl2.col_id'
         )
```

but it returns both tables  col_city column , so i just want col_city only from  Table1

so please tell me how i can do this in Magento2

Answer (score 1):

TO short out this issue if you have to use an alise column name for `Table2` 's column `col_city`.

If you want to  get the first table  column name then you can use `main_table.col_city` at join query.

But when if you want to get data using php collection object then you use an alise column name for `Table2` 's column `col_city`.

**Join Query:**

```
  $this->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                array('tbl2' => $this->getTable('Table2')),
                'main_table.col_tid = tbl2.col_id',
                [
                    'tbltwocity' => 'tbl2.col_city',
                    '*'
                ]

            );
```

**$collection** if collection object then you can second table's city  value by

```
foreach($collection as $each)
{
 $eachRow->getTbltwocity();
}
```

Comment: But how can you please share sample code

Comment: sure. i will share shortly